# new line is getting added in table().cell().range.text in word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I copy text from a cell in table using docCurrent.Tables(x).Cell(x, y).Range.Text, a new line is getting added along with the text in the cell.

The code I used is:

```
Sub tabele_trasfer()
'
' tabele_trasfer Macro
'
'
Dim docCurrent As Document
Dim docNew As Document
Dim myRange As Range

Set docCurrent = ActiveDocument
Set docNew = Documents.Add
Set myRange = docNew.Range(0, 0)

docNew.Tables.Add Range:=myRange, NumRows:=docCurrent.Tables(5).Rows.Count, NumColumns:=docCurrent.Tables(5).Columns.Count

For i = 1 To docCurrent.Tables(5).Rows.Count
    docNew.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=i, Column:=1).Range.Text = docCurrent.Tables(5).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text
    docNew.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=i, Column:=2).Range.Text = docCurrent.Tables(5).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be populating both columns in the new document with the same data. Try:

```
Sub tabele_trasfer()
'
' tabele_trasfer Macro
'
'
Dim docCurrent As Document
Dim docNew As Document
Dim myRange As Range

Set docCurrent = ActiveDocument
Set docNew = Documents.Add
Set myRange = docNew.Range(0, 0)

docNew.Tables.Add Range:=myRange, NumRows:=docCurrent.Tables(5).Rows.Count, NumColumns:=docCurrent.Tables(5).Columns.Count

For i = 1 To docCurrent.Tables(5).Rows.Count
    Set myRange = docCurrent.Tables(5).Cell(i, 2).Range
    myRange.End = myRange.End - 1
    docNew.Tables(1).Cell(i, 1).Range.Text = myRange.Text
    docNew.Tables(1).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text = myRange.Text
Next i

End Sub
```

If populating both columns in the new document with the same data is not your intent, use:

```
    Set myRange = docCurrent.Tables(5).Cell(i, 2).Range
    myRange.End = myRange.End - 1
```

again to point to the correct source before outputting the second string.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the end of a table cell contains two characters: Chr(13) & Chr(7) - a paragraph mark and the end-of-cell marker. You can cut these off to retain only the text.

I've provided a function I use for this purpose that takes the cell Range and returns the string value, below. Here's one of your lines, altered to use the function

```
docNew.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=i, Column:=1).Range.Text = _
           TrimCellText(docCurrent.Tables(5).Cell(i, 2).Range)
```

And the function

```
Function TrimCellText(r As word.Range) As String
    Dim sLastChar As String
    Dim sCellText As String

    sCellText = r.Text
    sLastChar = Right(sCellText, 1)
    Do While sLastChar = Chr(7) Or sLastChar = Chr(13)
        sCellText = Left(sCellText, Len(sCellText) - 1)
        sLastChar = Right(sCellText, 1)
    Loop
    TrimCellText = sCellText
End Function
```